# Generic push to a Stack gives compilation error

Tags: java, generics

I have a Node class defined as following -

```
public static class Node<T> {
    public T value;
    public Node<T> left;
    public Node<T> right;

    public Node(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to add/push a `Node<Integer>` to a `Stack<Node<T>>` and it gives me a compilation error.

```
private static <T> Node<T> createTree(Expression expression) {
    Stack<Node<T>> nodeStack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Token> tokenStack = new Stack<>();

    Token token = getNextToken(expression);

    while (token != null) {
        if (token instanceof OpenParenthesis) {
            tokenStack.push(token);
        } else if (token instanceof Element) {
            nodeStack.push(new Node<Integer>(((Element) token).value)); // Here
        } else if (token instanceof EmptyElement) {
            nodeStack.push(null);
        } else if (token instanceof CloseParenthesis) {
            if (nodeStack.size() == 1) {
                tokenStack.pop();
                return nodeStack.pop();
            }

            tokenStack.pop();
            Node<T> right = nodeStack.pop();
            Node<T> left = nodeStack.pop();
            Node<T> node = nodeStack.pop();
            node.left = left;
            node.right = right;
            nodeStack.push(node);
        }

        token = getNextToken(expression);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This line doesn't compile -

```
nodeStack.push(new Node<Integer>(((Element) token).value));
```

with message -

> `push(Node<T>)` in `Stack` cannot be applied to `(Node<java.lang.Integer>)`

Comment: Well, yeah.  `T` can be any type, such as `String`.  If it's a `String`, how do you expect to push an integer on the stack?  I suspect maybe you don't want `createTree` to be generic; maybe it should return a `Node<Object>` so that you can create a tree with nodes of different classes.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to cast a `Token` into a `Number`?  That won't compile.

Comment: My bad, I have a local class `Number`, which I haven't mentioned here. I will rename it to remove confusion.

Comment: You should avoid naming types the same as those in the Java API, particularly​ in the `java.lang....` and `java.util....` families of packages. You saw why just now. Source code is for humans. Respect the humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<T>` type parameter is a method level parameter. I.e. you defined it at the method signature:

```
private static <T> Node<T> createTree(Expression expression
```

Your node stack has the very same type:

```
Stack<Node<T>> nodeStack = new Stack<>();
```

So when you push into that stack, you need the very same type token:

```
nodeStack.push(new Node<T>(((Element) token).value));
//                   ^^^^^^ - using <T>
```

So, how do you make it work for you? If you are sure that all push to `nodeStack` will be `null` and `Node<Integer>` - this is how it seems - then you can get rid of the method-level type token:

```
private static Node<Integer> createTree(Expression expression) {
    Stack<Node<Integer>> nodeStack = new Stack<>();
    // ...
    } else if (token instanceof Element) {
         nodeStack.push(new Node<Integer>(((Element) token).value)); // Here
    }
    // ...
            Node<Integer> right = nodeStack.pop();
            Node<Integer> left = nodeStack.pop();
            Node<Integer> node = nodeStack.pop();
    // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that I can make `createTree()` return a `Node<Integer>`, however, sometimes, I can have a `String` instead of the `Integer`. I will have to create a separate `createTree()` that returns a `Node<String>` instead.

Comment: If you know if it's `String` or `Integer` at compile time, then you can go with the typed method, i.e. the one with `nodeStack.push(new Node<T>(((Element) token).value));`. In this case you can specify the `<T>` type like this: `OuterClass.<String>createTree(...)` or `OuterClass.<Integer>createTree(...)`.

Comment: Can you take look at the question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163061/creating-a-tree-from-an-input-string-1-2-3-10-11-15-4-5-13-6) - I have added more details. This might clarify what I want to say. I did not want to edit the question here (it might change what I previously asked).

Comment: Refer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/163067/56383) for the complete solution.

Comment: @yadav_vi Are you trying to create a tree that can have both `String` and `Integer` nodes in it, at the same time?

Comment: @ajb It might be a possibility, please have a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163061/creating-a-tree-from-an-input-string) for this question in detail.

Comment: @yadav_vi Sorry, it's too long to read.  But if you want a tree that has some `String` nodes and some `Integer` nodes, then generics aren't the answer.  Roughly speaking, generic data structures are mostly useful when all the elements have the same type, but different structures could be for elements of different types.  Here, you want a tree structure where all the elements don't have to have the same type.  I wouldn't use a generic at all, and I'd declare the node `value` to be an `Object`.  That's the main way to handle heterogeneous data structures.